# Connection on a vector bundle in terms of sections

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Reference for this question is the book Geometry of Differential forms by Morita, page no 191.

In last but one paragraph it says the following,

> Suppose we are given an arbitrary bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow M$  with a  connection $\nabla$. We think of $\nabla s$ as  a $1$ form on $M$ whose value on vector field $X$ on $M$  is the section $\nabla_Xs$.

Connection on a vector bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ is a bilinear map $\nabla:X(M)\times \Gamma(E)\rightarrow\Gamma(E)$ satisfying certain conditions where $X(M)$ is the collection of vector fields on $M$ and $\Gamma(E)$ is collection of  sections of vector bundle.

I do not really understand the one that I have quoted above.

$1$ form on $M$  is a $\omega:M\rightarrow \Lambda(TM)$. They are saying $\nabla_s$ is a $1$ form on $M$. We need to say what is $\nabla_s:M\rightarrow \Lambda(TM)$.

Let $m\in M$ then, $\nabla_s(m):T_mM\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let us fix some vector field $X$ on $M$. We need to define $\nabla_s(m)(X(m))$.

Suppose we are in trivial vector bundle, where sections are just smooth maps on $M$ we can define $\nabla_s(m)(X(m))$ as $\nabla_X(s)(m)\in \mathbb{R}$. I do not see how we can think of $\nabla_s$ as a $1$ form  for a bundle which is not trivial.

I see that they are trying to relate connection on a vector bundle to be something that takes a section on $E$ and gives a section on some bundle, definitely not a section on $M$ as they have written. 
I fail to understand this.

A connection on a vector bundle is a map that takes a section on $M$ and gives a section on ..????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Morita is saying $\nabla s$ is an $E$-*valued* 1-form on $M$, i.e. a map $M\mapsto \wedge(TM)\otimes E$. The map $\nabla s$ takes $m\in M$ to the map $(\nabla s)_m: T_mM\rightarrow E_m$ (where $E_m$ is the fibre of $E$ at $m$), given by $(\nabla s)_m(X_m) := (\nabla_Xs)(m)$. Here $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is any vector field that agrees with $X_m$ at $m$. One can show from the properties of the connection that this quantity is independent of the choice of extension $X$.

Comment: I do not know very much about tensor product of vector bundles. I only know some basic definitions.... $E$ is a vector bundle over $M$ and $\Lambda T(M)$ is a vector bundle over $M$. So, we are taking its tensor product and get a vector bundle $E\otimes \Lambda(TM)$. And I believe $\nabla_s$ you have defined above is a section of this bundle. I do not see why would $\nabla_s(m)$ is in such form, I only know that $\nabla_s(m)$ is in fiber of $E\otimes \Lambda TM$ at $m$. I don’t know why such an element is a map that you have defined above

Comment: Ok. So you accept $(\nabla s)(m)$ is in the fibre of $\wedge(TM)\otimes E$ at $m$, i.e. $\wedge(TM)_m\otimes E_m$. The first factor gives a linear map from $T_xM$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (in other words, a 1-form at $m$). The second factor gives an element of $E_m$. Overall, you get a linear map from $T_xM$ to $E_m$, that is, an $E$-valued 1-form.

Comment: I think I understand. Let $a\otimes b\in (T_mM)^*\otimes E_m$ be a basis element. We have $a:T_mM\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $b\in E_m$. Combining these two we would get a map $T_mM\rightarrow E_m$ defined by $v\mapsto a(v)b$. This is well defined as $a(v)$ is a real number and $a(v)b\in E_m$ given $b\in E_m$ as $E_m$ is a real vectorspace

Comment: 6In general any element of $(T_mM)^*\otimes E_m$ is actually a map $T_mM\rightarrow E_m$.. can you give any refer nice for these concepts. We have to also see that if $Y$ is any other vector field whose value at $m$ is same as $X_m$ then $\nabla_Xs(m)=\nabla_Ys(m)$.

Comment: By linearity, the latter property is equivalent to showing that if $X$ vanishes at $m$, then $(\nabla_Xs)(m)=0$. To see this, pick a local coordinate system $(x^i)$, so $X=X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. $X$ vanishing at $m$ means that the functions $X^i$ all vanish at $m$. Then $\nabla_Xs = X^i\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}s$. Evaluating this at $m$ shows that $\nabla_Xs$ vanishes at $m$.

Comment: As for a good reference on this stuff, really most books on differential geometry. For example, [Tu has a discussion in his latest book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bmsmDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=tu+%22connections+at+a+point%22&source=bl&ots=QyK86BKgGG&sig=Uq2_1asZoqJAUflIgDJ0ZMWfdkw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5qJ6H4-7YAhVkUd8KHRS9D2MQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=tu%20%22connections%20at%20a%20point%22&f=false). I haven't read this, but it's probably pretty good based on his previous books.